# add column to mysql query plus give it value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure how to do this but I have a query that has unions in it. and i want to be able to diff each one by added a column. How do I add this column and give it a value. Thanks!

```
Select ID,Name,SpecialColumn = 'Test'
from table where ID = 'guid';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the string literal followed by a column alias `'Test' AS SpecialColumn` .  This will produce the same value for all rows returned, useful for differentiating between `UNION` components, or filling out mismatched column numbers between `UNION` components when necessary.

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Name,
 'Test' AS SpecialColumn
FROM table
WHERE ID = 'guid';
```

Output (ignoring your where clause) would be something like:

```
ID  Name     SpecialColumn
--------------------------
1   Venkman  Test
2   Egon     Test
1   Winston  Test
3   Ray      Test
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed, I knew it would be simple.